# I want to use emit to switch between page components

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3, emit

I have a Header and a Main page on Top page now, and I have three Tab functions in the Header component. I want to switch displays(A, B, C) in the Main page when I press each Tab (A, B, C). I am trying to change it using **Emit** but it doesn't work. If you could give me some advice, I really appreciate it.

Header.vue

```
<script setup >
const tabs = [
  {name: 'A', comp: A},
  {name: 'B', comp: B},
  {name: 'C', comp: C}
];

interface Emits {
  (e: "clicked", value: any);
}

const clicked = defineEmits<Emits>();
</script>

<template>
<div class="tabs" >
        <button v-bind:class="['tab-button', A]" @click="$emit('clickedA',tabs[0])">A</button>
        <button v-bind:class="['tab-button', B]" @click="$emit('clickedB',tabs[1])">B</button>
        <button v-bind:class="['tab-button', C]" @click="$emit('clickedC',tabs[2])">C</button>
</div>
</template>
```

Mainpage.vue

```
<script>
let currentTab = A

function getValue(event) {
    currentTab = event
}


</ script>

<template>
  <Header />
  <div>
    <component :is="currentTab" @clicked="getValue"></component> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Why not have all 3 buttons emit the same event, but pass different parameters to the event?

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Ask if anything is confusing or doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have the 3 buttons all call the same emit method, passing in the component String as a parameter of that emit:

```js
<button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
    @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[0])">
    A
</button>
<button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
    @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[1])">
    B
</button>
<button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
    @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[2])">
    C
</button>
```

Then, in the parent component, you could listen for that emit and that one alone:

```js
<Header @myClicked="getValue" />
```

and in script:

```js
function getValue(tab) {
  currentTab.value = tab.name;
}
```

For example:

Mainpage.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Header @myClicked="getValue" />
    <div>
      <component :is="currentTab"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Header from "./Header.vue";

let currentTab = ref("A");

function getValue(tab) {
  currentTab.value = tab.name;
}

function getTab(tab) {
  currentTab.value = tab.name;
}
</script>
```

Header.vue

```js
<script setup>
const tabs = [{ name: "A" }, { name: "B" }, { name: "C" }];

const emit = defineEmits(["myClicked"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="tabs">
    <button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
        @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[0])">
      A
    </button>
    <button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
        @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[1])">
      B
    </button>
    <button v-bind:class="['tab-button']" 
        @click="$emit('myClicked', tabs[2])">
      C
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

A, B, and C.vue:

```js
<template>
  <h2>Component A</h2>
</template>
```

```js
<template>
  <h2>Component B</h2>
</template>
```

```js
<template>
  <h2>Component C</h2>
</template>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'

import A from "./components/A.vue";
import B from "./components/B.vue";
import C from "./components/C.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.component("A", A);
app.component("B", B);
app.component("C", C);

app.mount('#app')
```

---

OCD cleaning up code a little more.
Using v-for in the Header.vue file to simplify the creation of buttons, and passing the name field into the emit's method parameter changes the following vue files:

Header.vue

```js
<script setup>
const tabs = [
  // assuming that in "real" code, 
  // the display name and component name values would likely be different
  { name: "A", compName: "A" },
  { name: "B", compName: "B" },
  { name: "C", compName: "C" },
];

const emit = defineEmits(["myClicked"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="tabs">
    <button
      v-for="tab in tabs"
      :key="tab.name"
      @click="$emit('myClicked', tab.compName)"
    >
      {{ tab.name }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Mainpage.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Header @myClicked="getValue" />
    <div>
      <component :is="currentTab"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Header from "./Header.vue";

let currentTab = ref("A");

function getValue(tabName) {
  currentTab.value = tabName;
}

function getTab(tab) {
  currentTab.value = tab.name;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I changed the 3 buttons all call the same emit method, and that worked!